# Replace specific characters in std::string with spaces

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stdstring

Following code removed punctuation marks correctly from char array:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char line[] = "ts='TOK_STORE_ID'; one,one, two;four$three two";
    for (char* c = line; *c; c++)
    {
        if (std::ispunct(*c))
        {
            *c = ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

How would this code look if the `line` is of type `std::string`?

Comment: You can use the `std::string` array access operator `[]` to manipulate single characters in the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'd look like following, if you simply prefer to use a STL algorithm

```
#include<algorithm>

std::string line ="ts='TOK_STORE_ID'; one,one, two;four$three two";

std::replace_if(line.begin() , line.end() ,  
            [] (const char& c) { return std::ispunct(c) ;},' ');
```

Or if you don't want to use STL

Simply use:

> ```
> std::string line ="ts='TOK_STORE_ID'; one,one, two;four$three two";
> std::size_t l=line.size();
> for (std::size_t i=0; i<l; i++)
> {
>     if (std::ispunct(line[i]))
>     {
>         line[i] = ' ';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @Karimkhan define "does not work" ? These `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~` are punctuation based on default locale that will be replaced with a space.

Comment: @POW: sorry, When I passed above strin in command line it treated as single word! But there was mistake at myside!

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc;
    std::string line = "ts='TOK_STORE_ID'; one,one, two;four$three two";

    for (std::string::iterator it = line.begin(); it!=line.end(); ++it)
            if ( std::ispunct(*it,loc) ) *it=' ';

    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
bool fun(const char& c)
{
  return std::ispunct(static_cast<int>(c));
}

int main()
{
  std::string line = "ts='TOK_STORE_ID'; one,one, two;four$three two";
  std::replace_if(line.begin(), line.end(), fun, ' ');
}
```

Comment: Do you need the wrapper function? Can't you just pass `std::ispunct` directly?

Comment: @KerrekSB It would be a bit fiddly because `std::ispunct` expects an `int`. I opted for the wrapped function for clarity (actually, I got lazy). Of course, a lambda would have been fine too.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line = "ts='TOK_STORE_ID'; one,one, two;four$three two";
    for (int i = 0;i<line.length();i++)
    {
        if (ispunct(line[i]))
        {
            line[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    cout << line << std::endl;
    cin.ignore();
}
```